# What does "Reverts to type in" means?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, british-english, phrase-meaning, semantics

What does "Reverts to type in" means in this headline:

"Donald Trump **reverts to type in** debate – and it isn't 'magnificently brilliant"

Comment: Read it as "In debate, Donald Trump reverts to type." To *revert to type* means to return to one's typical behavior. See https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/revert+to+type or https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/british/revert-to

Comment: @d_b your comment is the basis of an answer

Answer (score 1):

It means to return to usual behavior or form after a temporary change.

Comment: This would be improved by adding a source reference.

Comment: Again a style used in Indian office writing: Please revert with complete details; it means 'please reply...'  I don't know how correct this usage is.

Comment: @RamPillai: "Revert" in that sense is perfectly correct (it's used in British English too, but usually only in more formal settings e.g. lawyers often use it in their letters), but it's a different meaning to the one here.